# how to set number separated by comma in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, report

How to set number in crystal report separated by commas.
There is a provision for thousand separator. But actually i need the number in the form like the below example.
Eg : 12,34,556.00
not like 1,23,456.00

Comment: What is your exact requirement

Comment: need to show to the figure in the form of ##,##,##,###.##

Comment: thousand separator gives the number in the form like ###,###,###.##

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you probably want is Indian currency format i.e Lakhs and not Millions.
This is based on your culture information.

You can use a formula to format each field.  Right-click on one of your numeric fields, select "Format Field" and select the Common tab.  Click on the formula (X+2) button to the right of "Display String" near the bottom and enter a formula like:

```
CStr (CurrentFieldValue, "#,##,##,##,##,###.00")
```

Give this a try and see if it displays correctly.

Comment: Great. For next time, please make sure you post a question that can be easily understood by everyone.